# Mittag-Leffler Proof. Rudin notation question and some basic real analysis/topology

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

> [image]

Proof is below

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

1. What is meant by $\sum_{\alpha \in A_n}$? I thought $P_\alpha$ is a sum already.
2. What is this open set he is talking about? Because $A_n$ isn't open. Oh he means the complement of $A_n$? That is $A^c \cup  K_{m - 1} - K_m$? I thought $A$ is open though?
3. So I think my question 1 is correct. I guess $Q_1(z) = \sum_{\alpha} P_\alpha(z) = P_\alpha(z)$, and the same is for $Q_n(z) = \sum_{\alpha} P_\alpha(z) = P_\alpha(z)$

**EDIT**: editing right now, I forgot to put the last part of the proof…

Answer (score 1):

1. Each $P_\alpha$ is a sum, but then you sum these over the index set $\alpha \in A_n$. (Think partial fractions decomposition; Mittag-Leffler's theorem can be seen as a generalization of partial fractions to the infinite case.)
2. The function $Q$ is rational, and there are no poles in the compact set $K_{n-1}$. Hence $Q$ is in fact holomorphic on some open neighbourhood of $K_{n-1}$. (Since $Q$ is rational, it only has finitely many poles, so there must be a positive distance between $K_{n-1}$ and the closest pole.)
3. I don't understand the question here, $Q_n$ is defined in equation (1).

Comment: 1.$$ \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{-m(j)}   ^j}{(z-z_j)^{m(j)}} + \frac{a_{-m(j) + 1}   ^j}{(z-z_j)^{m(j)-1}} + \dots + \dots \frac{a_{-1}   ^j}{(z-z_j)}$$?

Comment: 3. I am trying to explain the blue box in my own words. Is it saying basically, $Q_1$ is the principal part and the $\sum ( R_n - Q_n)$ is the analytic part?